# Linear algebra help please

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $r$.

a) Assume that $Ax=b$ has infinitely many solutions for every $b$. What conditions must $m$, $n$ and $r$ obey?

b) Assume that $Ax=b$ has at least one solution for every $b$. What conditions must $m$, $n$ and $r$ obey?

c) Say $m=55$, $n=22$ and $r=13$. How many linearly independent vectors satisfy $Ax=0$? How many linearly independent vectors satisfy $A^Ty=0$?

Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

For (a) and (b): 
Have you ever seen the concept of "consistency" when solving Ax = b?  That concept will give you important information about how m, n and r should "behave"

For (c):  There is one definition saying the rank = number linearly independent rows/columns vectors.  How would this having any effect when we want to solve for Ax = 0?  Once we know that, it's easier to work with the second equation.

Hope this helps ^^

Answer (score 0):

a)

If there is at least one solution for every $b$ in $\mathbb R^m$, the rank of the matrix must be $m$(there must be a unique pivot for each entry in $b$).  If there are infinitely many solutions for every $b$, there also must be a "free column," so $r < n$.
$$m=r<n$$

b)

For the same reason as above, $r=m$. There must be at least $r$ (pivot) columns in the matrix, and more ($n>r$) if there are multiple solutions.
$$m=r\le n$$

c)

Given $Ax=0$, we are solving for the dimension of the nullspace of $A$, which is $n-r = 22-13 = 9$.

Given $A^Ty=0$, we are solving for the dimension of the nullspace of $A^T$, which is $m-r = 55-13=42$